# Android doesnt write to a file when using intent

Tags: java, android, file

This code makes the file "amirLight.txt" and saves the data to it. However, I am trying to create more files in the app and save the data to the new file. This doesn't work. Even though the file name selected and the variable "currentProject" correctly gets the value and shown correctly in Log.e but the actual data never saves to the new file. It only works when the default file of "amirLight.txt" is used.

```
package com.jorc.lightamir;

import static android.util.Log.e;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mLight;
    private float currentLux = 0;
    private float rotationVal = 0;
    private TextView lightValue;
    private TextView gpsX;
    private TextView gpsY;
    private TextView gpsZ;
    private TextView rotation;
    public Uri uriFile;
    public String currentProject ="amirLight.txt";


    //Location
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private double wayLatitude = 0.0, wayLongitude = 0.0;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private boolean isContinue = true;
    private boolean isGPS = false;
    private String testData = "TestData";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lightValue = findViewById(R.id.lightText);
        gpsX = findViewById(R.id.gpsX);
        gpsY = findViewById(R.id.gpsY);
        gpsZ = findViewById(R.id.gpsZ);
        rotation = findViewById(R.id.rotationText);




        lightValue.setText( "currentLux" );
        this.mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        this.mLight = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        //Location

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); // 5 seconds

        new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        if (!isContinue) {
                            gpsX.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude));
                            gpsY.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLongitude));
                        } else {

                        }
                        if (!isContinue && mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        isContinue = true;
        //End Location
        Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        Button projectSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.project_save);
        Button projectOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.project_open);

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();

                e("RecordSaved", "RecordSaved" );
            }
        });
        projectSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createFile();
            }
        });
        projectOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //createFile();
                openFile();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {

            currentLux = (float) sensorEvent.values[0];

            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");
            lightValue.setText( formatter.format(currentLux) );

            /* Logs */
            //Log.e("LightMeter", "currentLux = " + formatter.format(currentLux));
        }
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR)
        {
            rotationVal = (float) sensorEvent.values[2];
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");
            rotation.setText(formatter.format(rotationVal));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        }
    }

    //Location Additional
    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    AppConstants.LOCATION_REQUEST);

        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                if (location != null) {
                    wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(this, wayLatitude+"this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Write to a file
                    writeToFile("Lux "+currentLux+" Y "+wayLatitude+" X "+wayLongitude,currentProject,getApplicationContext());
                    // End write to a file

                    gpsX.setText(String.valueOf(wayLatitude));
                    gpsY.setText(String.valueOf(wayLongitude));
                } else {
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // create text file
    private void createFile() {
        // when you create document, you need to add Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

        // filter to only show openable items.
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // Create a file with the requested Mime type
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "typeProjectName.txt");

        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }
    private void openFile() {
        // when you create document, you need to add Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

        // filter to only show openable items.
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // Create a file with the requested Mime type
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, currentProject);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
    }





    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (isContinue) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                    } else {
                        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                            if (location != null) {
                                wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                gpsX.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude));
                                gpsY.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLongitude));


                            } else {
                                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
                isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
            }
        }
        //Open File
        if (requestCode == 3){

            if (data != null){
                if (data.getData() != null){
                    //Get file extension here.
                    // e("OpenFile", "OpenFile = " );
                    uriFile = data.getData();
                    currentProject=getFileName(uriFile);
                    Log.e("data", "FilePath2 = "+currentProject );

                }
            }
        }
        //End Open FIle

        //Create File
        if (requestCode == 2){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                if (data != null){
                    if (data.getData() != null){
                        uriFile = data.getData();
                         currentProject=getFileName(uriFile);
                        //Get file extension here.
                        e("CreateFIle", "CreateFIle = "+currentProject );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Create FIle



    }

    //Get File URI
    public  String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = { "_data" };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Eat it
            }
        }
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }


    //Write to File
    private void writeToFile(String data,String currentProject, Context context) {
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
       // if (currentProject == "1") {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose a project first");
            //Log.e("FileWrite", "No currentProject");
       // } else {

            File file = new File(dir, currentProject);
            Log.e("FileWrite", currentProject);

//Write to file
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
                Log.e("FileWrite", "Trying to write to file");

                fileWriter.append(data);
                fileWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
                //file=null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Handle exception
            }
       // }
    }
    //}


    //End of Write

    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
                result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: `public String currentProject ="amirLight.txt";` Please write readable code. If that is a file name then name it `public String fileName ="amirLight.txt";`

Comment: Your writeToFile function has a fileName parameter which you use together with  getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). That makes no sense if you started with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. You should use the obtained uri to write to the file of that uri.

Comment: `Android doesnt write to a file when using intent` ??? You mean: `Android doesnt write to a file when using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps.  When I start the app "amirLight.txt" works as a new file and data is added. The intent is only to get the file name so I can create a new file or open an existing file. When I pass the file name to writeToFile it doesn't save the data to that file for some reason. Intent does not open the file and I read there is no method to close the file and that wasnt the issue. I use the variable currentProject to save the data to a file, it only works when I define that variable initially. fileName parameter is only for guide, it can be changed by the user.

Comment: `The intent is only to get the file name` The intent? You mean ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT? A pretty bad idea as it will create an empty file too. And you are not usin the uri to write to. Why not make an input box to ask the user for a file name?

Comment: well, there are two intents. One is to create a file and the other one is to open the file. Does this cause any issue?

Comment: We can not continue if you keep talking about intents instead of naming the action.

Comment: I have writeTofile method which works fine. intents are only to get the file name? not sure why we are talking about these intents.

Comment: Also when I open  amirLight.txt it starts recording to this file. Open method only works when I choose the file initially created.